# Вывести листья бинарного дерева с парными значениями

Tags: c#, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Как вивесты в консоль листвы дерева, которие имеют парные значения?

```
public class BinaryTree
{
    public int Value;
    public BinaryTree Left = null;
    public BinaryTree Right = null;
    public BinaryTree(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public void Add(int value)
    {
        if (value < Value)
        {
            if (Left == null) Left = new BinaryTree(value);
            else Left.Add(value);
        }
        else if (value > Value)
        {
            if (Right == null) Right = new BinaryTree(value);
            else Right.Add(value);
        }
    }
}

class BT
{
    // Зворотній обхід бінарного дерева
    public static void SimPrintTree(BinaryTree root)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            SimPrintTree(root.Left);
            SimPrintTree(root.Right);
            Console.Write(root.Value + "  ");
        }
    }

    public static void SimOutputEvenLeaves(BinaryTree root)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            SimOutputEvenLeaves(root.Left);
            // check for excistance of leaves:
            if (root.Left != null & root.Right != null)
            {
                if (root.Left.Value % 2 == 0 || root.Right.Value % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{root.Value} ({root.Left.Value} + {root.Right.Value} = {root.Left.Value + root.Right.Value}");
                }
            }
            SimOutputEvenLeaves(root.Right);
        }
    }

    public static void SimPrintLeaves(BinaryTree root)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            SimPrintLeaves(root.Left);
            if (root.Left == null && root.Right == null)
            {
                Console.Write(root.Value + "  ");
            }
            SimPrintLeaves(root.Right);
        }
    }
    public static int addBT(BinaryTree root)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return (root.Value + addBT(root.Left) + addBT(root.Right));
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Input the tree's range: ");
        int rootValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(rootValue);
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < rootValue; i++)
        {
            int value = r.Next(10);
            tree.Add(value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Symetric tree preview:");
        SimPrintTree(tree);

        addBT(tree);

        PrintTree(tree);
        int sum = addBT(tree);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Парные — это в смысле чётные (те, которые делятся на 2)?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе примеры данных на входе и на выходе. Либо - определение "партности".

Answer (score 2):

Самый правильный метод — это получить последовательность ключей, а затем отфильтровать её при помощи LINQ.

Например, так:

```
IEnumerable<int> TraverseTree(BinaryTree root) =>
    root is null ?
        Enumerable.Empty<int>() :
        TraverseTree(root.Left).Concat(TraverseTree(root.Right)).Append(root.Value);
```

Имея такой обход, вы просто фильтруете последовательность:

```
foreach (var leaf in TraverseTree(tree).Where(n => n % 2 == 0))
{
    // делайте с листом что хотите
}
```

---

Если вы хотите исключить `Value` из нелистовых узлов, делайте так:

```
IEnumerable<int> TraverseLeaves(BinaryTree root) =>
    root is null ? Enumerable.Empty<int>() : // пустое дерево?
    root.Left is null && root.Right is null ? new[] { root.Value } : // лист?
    TraverseTree(root.Left).Concat(TraverseTree(root.Right)); // не лист?
```

Comment: И Linq'шно и изящно!

Comment: @AK: Ну, LINQ и вообще всякая функциональщина особенно хорошо работает на чистых, рекурсивных структурах.

Answer (score 2):

Так же можна вот так:

```
 public static void PrintTree(BinaryTree root)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            SimPrintTree(root.Left);              
            SimPrintTree(root.Right);
            if (root.Left == null && root.Right == null && root.Value % 2 == 0)
                Console.Write(root.Value + "  ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужно `PrintTree` вместо `SimPrintTree`.